# Prove there's always a larger element

Tags: proof-writing

We have a number $ 0 < x < 1 $. We also have the function $1-\dfrac{1}{n}$ with $n \in \mathbb{N}$. How can I prove that for any $x \in \mathbb{R}$, there exists an $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $ 1-\dfrac{1}{n} > x$?

Of course, my intuitive problem is that you should in theory also be able to prove the reverse, because we have $x \in \mathbb{R}$.

Does there exist a simple proof for this?

Comment: Simply take $ n > \frac{1}{1-x}$.

Comment: @Crostul How does that prove anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $n \in \mathbb{N}$ any natural number such that $n > \frac{1}{1-x}$.
Then
$$\frac{1}{n}<1-x$$
$$1- \frac{1}{n}>x$$

Comment: But is this really a proof? You just rewrote it. I know the statement is really trivial, but is the proof too?

Comment: Yes, it is trivial.